# Removing arbitrary, repetitive rotation of video, then removing residual shaking

Tags: video-editing

You took a video of kid crawling through some maze while crawling with her. The result is really shaky video with several wild rotations of camera. Like you started the recording as horizontal, and then somehow in the middle of route you change it to vertical and then back again. So rotate whole video by 90° is not sufficient at all.

Recently I saw same impressive shaking removal, where shaking was ~30° and yet the program was able to stabilize it and only the boundaries of video was witness of wild recording.

Can someone recommend any software to achieve this? I can manually assist with orientation of several frames, but I cannot orient thousands of them.

- Preferably free solution on Linux, optionally Windows
- small price for SW capable of doing so; say up to 50$?

But I'd really like to give a shot to variety of tools, and compare which does it best. So far I cannot even find out which SW can do all of that (ie. removing wild multiple rotations + shake removal)

Answer (score 1):

You can try use [Blender](https://www.blender.org)

- [2D Stabilization](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/movie_clip_editor/tracking/clip/properties/stabilization/index.html)
- external addons like [Highpass](https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-high-quality-video-stabilization/618552)
- Manual transformation and addon [VSE_Transform_Tools](https://github.com/doakey3/VSE_Transform_Tools)

But Blender is complex professional software, not 10-click solution at all.

Use [Youtube video guides](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender%20video%20stabilization&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)...

Blender is free, opensource and crossplatform.

PS.

*I use Blender as VSE editor under Linux, but for static camera video only.*

*After such extensive stabilisation I expect lost in subjective video quality...*

**UPD:**

- [vid.stab](https://github.com/georgmartius/vid.stab) in ffmpeg. But it need to be compiled in some distros...
  https://scottlinux.com/2016/09/17/video-stabilization-using-vidstab-and-ffmpeg-on-linux/
- For Wundows VirtualDub with [Deshaker](https://www.guthspot.se/video/deshaker.htm) can be used

**UPD2:**

I shoot some video which need stabilisation. In my case rotation not require much stabilisation. (Shoot from long handle)

- I tried "Blender 2D stabilisation" at first. Bit setting tracking points is manual work, require repeating for moving camera. Result has strange jumps (in rotation), and require manual adjustment footage from for moving camera.
- Next I do [vid.stab](https://github.com/georgmartius/vid.stab). It work automatic. Make good result. Can fill black borders... Basing on reading about vid.stab algorythm, I expect if video rotated and continue shoot in rotated position is hard be fixed by vid.stab.

> ```
> ffmpeg -i "$1" -vf vidstabdetect=shakiness=5 -f null -
> ffmpeg -n -i "$1" -vf vidstabtransform=optzoom=0:smoothing=30,unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4  "${1%.*}-stab30.mkv"`
> ```

- Most annoying for me problem ni vid.stab is wobbling effect, when stabilizing camera oscillations. But Look like it related to no "[global shutter](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/13480/22966)" in CCD.

### Try use vid.stab twice

First with limited rotation stabilisation to stabilise only camra motion

> ```
> ffmpeg -i source.MOV     -vf vidstabdetect    -f null -
> ffmpeg -i source.MOV     -vf vidstabtransform=maxangle=0.01:smoothing=30 source-step1.mp4
> ```

Second with in tripod mode (with full compensation) only for rotation

> ```
> ffmpeg -i source-step1.mp4  -vf vidstabdetect=tripod=1
> ffmpeg -i source-step1.mp4  -vf vidstabtransform=tripod=1:maxshift=0.1,unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4  source-step2.mp4
> ```

`tripod` set frame with reference rotation

Comment: Thanks for tips. One question: I assume just stabilization will not be able pick cca 100° rotation, right? And another question: how about quality of result? How much would you expect to drop? Since ... if it's noticeable, I'd rather live with improperly rotated video than low quality properly oriented one.

Comment: @MartinMucha Q1: My footage hawe no more that 40° rotation, but I don't see why not.
Q2: Quality generally good, but on shaky footage i get wobbling effect, related to rolling shutter. (https://www.shutterstock.com/contributorsupport/articles/kbat02/000011315?l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle) It not noticeable on shaky source, but visible after stabilisation. (https://www.google.com/search?q=video+stabilization+rolling+shutter+deformation )